# square eigenvectors for Singular Value Decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal, svd

This is from my textbook[image]

What I don't understand is, $V$ and $U$ are already square, why the textbook says "if we want to make them square"?

Comment: If $A$ is not square or does not have full rank, $U$ and $V$ are not square.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let us assume that $A$ is $n \times p$ in "portrait" format ($n>p$).

Then $V$ is $p \times r$ and  $U$ is $p \times r$ ($r$ being the rank)